# Problem with creating tower defense money farm script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

im pretty new to coding so maybe the answer is simple.

Im creating a tower defense game and right now im trying to code a tower, which adds a serializable amount of money after each wave is defeated.

My idea is that the script which controls the WaveSpawning should call all MoneyPumps to perform the function "GiveMoney()", that sits on their script MoneyPump. But there is a problem with static stuff, which I cant find a solution to.

Please help,
thanks.

The Segment for WaveSpawning:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if(spawningWave){return;} 
        if(GameManager.gameOver){enabled = false; return;}

        maxWavePlayTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(enemiesAlive > 0 && maxWavePlayTime >= 0f)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(waveIndex == waves.Length && !spawningWave)
        {
            gameManager.LevelWon();
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

//THE IDEA IS TO CALL HERE THE MONEY PUMPS 1 TIME


        if(Countdown <= 0f )
        {
            Stats.WavesSurvived++;
            waveToDisplay = waveIndex + 1;
            WaveIndexDisplay.text = "Wave " + waveToDisplay.ToString();
            spawningWave = true;
            StartCoroutine(SpawnWave());
            Countdown = WaveCounter;
            maxWavePlayTime = StartmaxWavePlayTime;
            return;
        }
```

The short script for MoneyPumps:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoneyPump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int moneyEveryRound = 25;
    public static bool giveMoney = false;

    public void GiveMoney()
    {
        Stats.Money += moneyEveryRound;
    }
}
```

The stuff to spawn a turret:
1.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TurretBluePrint
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int cost;
    public GameObject upgradedPrefab;
    public int upgradeCost;
    public int SellDivider;
}
```

2. If we click on a designated Button the SelectMoneyPump() function gets called

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TurretBluePrint LaserBeamer;
    public void SelectMoneyPump()
    {
        Debug.Log("Money Pump Purchased");
        BuildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(MoneyPump);
    }
}
```

3. 

```
    public void SelectTurretToBuild (TurretBluePrint turret)
    {
        turretToBuild = turret; 
        DeselectNode();
    }
```

4. If we now click on a node (basically a just a tile on a grid):

```
public class Node : MonoBehaviour
{
...
void OnMouseDown()
...
BuildTurret(buildmanager.GetTurretToBuild());
...
}


public class BuildManager : MonoBehaviour
{
...
    public TurretBluePrint GetTurretToBuild()
    {
        return turretToBuild;
    }
...
}
```

5. Turret building

```
void BuildTurret(TurretBluePrint blueprint)
{
...
turretBlueprint = blueprint;
GameObject _turret = (GameObject)Instantiate(blueprint.prefab, 
GetBuildPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
...

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `GiveMoney` methods, you need to store your `MoneyPump` instances somewhere. For example you can store it inside `WaveSpawning` and then just call `GiveMoney` inside foreach loop

```cs
class WaveSpawning
{
    private List<MoneyPump> moneyPumps;
    ...
    void Update()
    {
        ...
        foreach(var mp in MoneyPump)
            mp.GiveMoney();
        ...
    }
}
```

So when you create new `MoneyPump` instance you add it to the `moneyPumps`. However it's not the best practice to store `MoneyPump` inside `WaveSpawning`, because it's wrong abstraction.
I would recommend to handle end of wave inside another class.

```cs
class WavesSystem
{
    // Singleton pattern
    private static _wavesSystem _instance;
    // If you use C# 8 or newer
    private static WavesSystem Instance => _instance ??= new WavesSystem();
    // If you use older version
    private static WaveSystem Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new WavesSystem())

    private WavesSystem()
    {
    }

    public void BeginWave()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void FinishWave()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that previous example is ok, when your `WavesSystem` doesn't need to be `MonoBehavior`, otherwise try [another `singleton` logic](https://gamedevbeginner.com/singletons-in-unity-the-right-way/)

```cs
class WavesSystem : MonoBehavior
{
    public static WavesSystem Instance { get; private set; }
    private void Awake() 
    { 
        // If there is an instance, and it's not me, delete myself.
    
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
            Destroy(this); 
        else 
            Instance = this; 
    }
    ...
}
```

**Important**: `Instance` of `WavesSystem` will not be null after `Awake`, so do not get access to `WavesSystem.Instance` in another `Awake` method, because it can be tricky (sometimes your classA will be loaded before WavesSytem and it will work, but when you build your app, loading order can change and it will cause an error)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the first idea since its easier to understand. The code works, I just need to do the second part, actually adding the gameobjects to the list. The problem is that the spawning part is a bit complicated. I cant just simply add a counter there. Is there a way to make the Wavespawner search for objects with a specific tag and add them to the list? I tried:  `MoneyPump[] moneyPumps = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MoneyPumps");` but this gives me error0029 because I cant convert UnityEngine.GameObject[] to MoneyPump[]

Comment: `FindGameObjects` is a bad idea. You need to add `MoneyPump` to list when it's creating. Where do you create `MoneyPump`?

Comment: I added the information to the main thread because it would have been way too long for a comment. I thought maybe it is possible to check the name of a prefab and if it is MoneyPump then add it to a list. But I cant find a way to check the names of prefabs without even more errors showing up

Comment: You can implement singleton `WavesSystem` as I've shown (make List<MoneyPump> public), then inside `BuildTurret` method after you instantiate your prefab just put new turret to the list `WavesSystem.Instance.MoneyPumps.Add(_turret)`

Comment: Singletons are completely new to me. To be honest I dont fully understand what you wrote there. Furthermore the WaveSpawner script must be Monobehaviour for me because of other elements not shown in the things I uploaded here. Is there no other solution? I feel like its pretty simple actually

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution is harder to find than I thought. I simply changed the concept a bit. The MoneyPumps do not give money after every wave defeated but after a defined amount of time, which is way more easy to code.

```
public class MoneyPump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int moneyEveryRound = 25;
    public int moneyEverySeconds = 20;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GiveMoney());
    }

    IEnumerator GiveMoney()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(moneyEverySeconds);
        Stats.Money += moneyEveryRound;
        Debug.Log("MoneyGiven: " + moneyEverySeconds);
        StartCoroutine(GiveMoney());
    }
}
```